# "I was weeping while selling my car."

Tags: sentence-construction

> I was weeping while selling my car.

Can anyone tell me whether this statement is correct or not? Can I use 2 *-ing* words in one sentence?

Comment: What do you think? Why do you think so? What research have you done?

Comment: My mother was humming while ironing my dad's shirt; my dog was barking while running back and forth; my boss was glaring while tapping his fingers on his desk; the wind was making a low sound while stirring the leaves on the ground.

Comment: I'm sure I have seen something like this in a list of things used-car salesmen say to someone they are trying to sell a car to: "Buddy, I'm gonna be weeping while selling the car to you because the price is so low!"